# Button at alignParentBottom="true" in a fragment

Tags: android, xml

I have some different fragment in my app but when I add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the button it shows in the android studio "design" but in the app there is no button and when I remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` it shows the button with the `50dp` of `marginTop` and I have assigned the button to check internet connection and it works too.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.AboutAppFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFragmentAboutApp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_app_fragment"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnCheckInternet"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:text="Check Internet"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity of this fragment

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import com.first.bookhub.R
import com.first.bookhub.util.ConnectionManager

class AboutAppFragment : Fragment() {

 lateinit var btnCheckInternet : Button

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_app, container, false)
         btnCheckInternet = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckInternet)

        btnCheckInternet.setOnClickListener{
            if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(activity as Context))
            {
                val diaglog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
                diaglog.setTitle("Success")
                diaglog.setMessage("Internet Connection Found ")
                diaglog.setPositiveButton("ok"){text, listener -> //Do nothing
                }
                diaglog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){text, listener -> // do Nothing
                }
                diaglog.create()
                diaglog.show()
            }
            else
            {
                val diaglog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
                diaglog.setTitle("Error")
                diaglog.setMessage("Internet Connection is not Found ")
                diaglog.setPositiveButton("ok"){text, listener -> //Do nothing
                }
                diaglog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){text, listener -> //do Nothing
                }
                diaglog.create()
                diaglog.show()
            }
        }
       return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your activity layout in which you have tried to add the fragment?

Comment: added the activity code in the question